# -te iku form with repetition / habitual action

Tags: form

I'm learning both the -ていく/-てくる form to express something done during the movement and the -ている form to express a repetitive / custom action.

But, if I want to say that everyday I'm reading a book when I come to work, can I say :
まいにちかいしゃに本をよんでいいています。

It's difficult for me to understand how to combine these two forms.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: よんでいいて isn't a valid construction, because there is no verb whose -te form is いいて. You might expect it to be -te form of いく, but いく is an irregular verb, and conjugates to いって. So I think the sentence you intended was 毎{まい}日{にち}会{かい}社{しゃ}に本を読{よ}んで行{い}っています.

Comment: I don't think of  -ていく/-てくる as "expressing something done during the movement", and I don't think of -ている as expressing a repetitive/custom action - I usually think of the regular verb form doing that on its own (depending on context). I tend to think of it as being a current, ongoing state, and you can pretty much always translate it to an English sense by adding "-ing" to the end of the verb. Also if -ていく *did* mean that, then your example sentence would be saying "Every day I'm reading a book on my way to work", which it isn't.

Comment: (Note: for intransitive verbs, including いく/くる, -ている doesn't mean "-ing" but something else entirely. きている means "to have come (and still be here)") And in most cases that come to mind for me, -ていく/-てくる means to "do and then go/come back", not "do while going/coming". Your example sentence means "Every day I 'm reading a book and then going to work"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although 本を よんで いって いる is not wrong, you usually use 本を よみながら いって いる instead for that meaning.